# How to return after jQuery fadeOut has finished

Tags: jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Question</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>question {{ question.id }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                <img class="photo" src="{{ question.image_source }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 info">
                <h5>current score: {{ score }}</h5>
                <hr>
                <form method="POST">
                    okay {{ user }}, what country is this in? <input type="text" name="country_guess" id="guess" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
                    <br>
                    <span></span>
                    <textarea id="pointsWorth" name="pointsWorth" rows="1">3</textarea>
                </form>
                <div id="message"></div>
                <div class="wrong_answers">wrong answers:</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    let tries = 3;
    let wrongAnswers = [];

    $( "form" ).submit(function ( event ) {
        let guess = $('#guess').val().toUpperCase().trim();
        if ( guess === "{{ question.country }}") {
             $( "span" ).text( "Correct" ).show().fadeOut(3500).done(function() {
                alert('here');
                return;
        });
        }
        if ($.inArray(guess, wrongAnswers) !== -1){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='<p>You\'ve already guessed ' + guess + ' - try again!</p>';
        } else {
            $("span").text(" Wrong ").show().fadeOut(3500);
            wrongAnswers.push(guess);
            tries--;
            document.getElementById('pointsWorth').innerHTML = tries.toString();
            $( ".wrong_answers" ).append('<p>' + guess + '</p>');
        }
        if ( tries === 0) return;
        document.getElementById('guess').value='';
        $('input:text').focus( function() { $(this).val(''); });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the "Correct" message to show for the full 3.5 secs before it commits the return and reloads the page - any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I tried the :

```
if ( guess === "{{ question.country }}") {
 $( "span" ).text( "Correct" ).show().fadeOut(3500, function() {
     alert('here');
     return;  
 });
```

but it didn't work. a solution was to not initially call the form but the button, and then inside the fadeOut function to then submit the form:

```
$( "button" ).click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let guess = $('#guess').val().toUpperCase().trim();
    if ( guess === "{{ question.country }}") {
         $( "span" ).text( "Correct" ).show().fadeOut(3500, function() {
             $( "form" ).submit();
    });
```

Thanks for the help and hope this solution helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your page refreshes as soon as you click on the submit button in the form.
By default the form will do a POST request while refreshing the page and the `fadeOut()` wouldn't stop that from happening.

So to prevent the default behaviour add `event.preventDefault()` to the submit handler and then referring the form with `this` to a variable and then calling submit on that variable. Like so :

```
 $( "form" ).submit(function ( event ) {
        var thisForm = this;
        event.preventDefault(); // <-- Change 1 
        let guess = $('#guess').val().toUpperCase().trim();
        if ( guess === "{{ question.country }}") {
             $( "span" ).text( "Correct" ).show().fadeOut(3500,function(){
                  thisForm.submit(); // <-- Change 2
             })
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Boo, spot on what you wrote helped me arrive at the answer - cheers :)

Comment: your own answer too is spot on ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
if ( guess === "{{ question.country }}") {
     $( "span" ).text( "Correct" ).show().fadeOut(3500, function() {
         alert('here');
         return;  
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should go through this link for more details-

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-the-callback-function-with-fadein-and-fadeout-jquery